# Mismatching design of "we are offline" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Well, no site problem without the chance for a little design test. I noticed that other sites in the network employ a specialized "we are offline" site (not the 404 site or the "there was an error" site) congruent with their individual designs, here in an example from Science Fiction and Fantasy:
[image]

But when visiting ours, it wasn't our great new graduated design, but the generic StackExchange design:
[image]

Was this just a caching problem from my side, was this forgot to adapt in the graduation process or was this deliberately generalized for new SE sites?

Comment: Might be caching because to me it shows the new design or it might be possible either way.

Comment: HA! I was going to post this EXACT same thing. I took screen shots just like you did too. God, the things we notice.

Comment: At least you guys had text! [Check out what Travel.SE got!](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/issue-with-the-offline-page) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be viewed under `http://sstatic.net/movies/app_offline.htm`, our *"we are offline"* page has been largely updated to match the site's design (even though the color of visited links doesn't seem to match our site's color palette at all, but that could be considered a minor problem):

[image]

So it was likely just a caching problem.